# Angular Cannot find module of my custom library

Tags: angular, typescript, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I'm implementing SSR in my angular application, while trying to run `npm run build:ssr` it throws the below error.

I've created my own libs are it bundled in the dist folder in the name `@asfc/shared`

```
ERROR in projects/asfc-web/src/environments/environment.ts:1:39 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@asfc/shared' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import { PageNotFoundComponent } from '@asfc/shared';
                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
......
```

I've added the index.ts to the `files`, but still error is not going away

Below is my, `tsconfig.server.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "strict": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "../../dist/server",
    "lib": ["es2016", "DOM"],
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "server.ts",
    "../../dist/asfc-shared/public_api.d.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "entryModule": "../../projects/asfc-web/src/app/app.server.module.ts#AppServerModule"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

Below is my Dist Libs structure,

```
dist/asfc-shared
    ├── asfc-shared.d.ts
    ├── package.json
    ├── public_api.d.ts
```

Pleas help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding a path mapping in your `tsconfig.json`

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    
    ....
    
    "paths": {
      "@asfc/shared/*": [
        "../../dist/asfc-shared/*"
      ],

    }
  },
```

You also have `dist` folder excluded from your config, but I guess this is not the same folder as the one containing your lib.

Comment: would this be in the application or in the library tsconfig?